# What is the best easing function to simulate a GUI item dropping?

Tags: silverlight, animation, silverlight-4.0, expression-blend, easing-functions

There are so many easing functions available in Expression Blend, and so many settings on each, it is often hard to know instinctively what easing function to choose. Trying all the options would take quite a long time.

In this instance, I want to give the impression that the item has fallen forward and down. I am using a projection rotation about X and currently using one of the circular easing functions, but it does not *feel* quite right. A subtle bounce would probably help.

**What would be the best option (and specific settings) to give the impression of falling a short distance?**

As always, thanks in advance.

**Follow-up:** *After the comments below and as a potential long-term solution to the general problem posed here (choosing easing functions and settings by keyword), we have now setup [www.easing.co](http://www.easing.co). We will be seeking contributions from the community, so if you are interested in helping with the project, drop us a line via that website only.*

Comment: +1, A good question, I find that having tested a few myself they all seem to blur into one an I can no longer objectively scrutinize the variations.

Comment: @AnthonyWJones: I'm thinking an interactive Silverlight app, to play with *all* the options *and allowing people to input descriptive keywords for each combination*, might make a handy online database for the subjective selection of easing functions. What do you think?

Comment: That sounds like a good idea.

Comment: @AnthonyWJones: www.easing.co is now live (with a temporary blog). We hope it turns into a useful and well-used project. Thanks for the support.

Comment: @AnthonyWJones: We already run over 80 websites so spinning up another WP site is trivial... Just needed an idea and a suitable domain *(thank goodness for the new .co domains)* :)

Comment: You may have already seen this but there is a decent demo of the different easing functions at the bottom of the post: http://www.michaelsnow.com/2010/05/18/silverlight-tip-of-the-day-21-animation-easing-2/ Sounds like you are making your own interactive app to tackle this anyway but its worth a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came across this post whilst looking for an answer to the same question.

I Used a 'BounceOut' ease with 2 bounces, and a bounciness of 10.

Pete